# Change Swagger UI's "Schemas" to "Models"?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Swagger & Swagger UI use "Schemas" and "Models" interchangeably. I'd like to refer to them as Models on my Swagger UI instance (rather than Schemas), but can't find where to make this change.

I've attached 2 images that show where I'm referring to. I'd like to erase all references of "Schemas" from the page, and replace them with "Model", similar to how it appears on many of Swagger's test sites (example: [petstore.swagger.io](https://petstore.swagger.io/#/)) that they've created.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uj89.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgAAJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Swagger & Swagger UI use "Schemas" and "Models" interchangeably.

Just to clarify - Swagger UI uses "Schema" when rendering OpenAPI 3 definitions, and "Model" when rendering OpenAPI 2.0 definitions. With this in mind, "Model" is sort of an outdated term.

If you still want to see the "Model" label in Swagger UI regardless of your OpenAPI version, you'll have to fork [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/), change the label in the code, and build and use your own version. (And rebuild it whenever you want to use a newer Swagger UI release.)

The lines you need to change are:

- [src/core/components/model-example.jsx](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/model-example.jsx#L97)

  ```js
  {isOAS3 ? "Schema" : "Model" }
  ```

  change to

  ```js
  "Model"
  ```
- [src/core/components/models.jsx](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/models.jsx#L67)

  ```js
  <span>{isOAS3 ? "Schemas" : "Models"}</span>
  ```

  change to

  ```js
  <span>"Models"</span>
  ```